# In python lxml how to read from string and process using etree.iterparse()

Tags: python-3.x, xml, lxml

so i am currently reading a file from s3 and i need to use  etree.iterparse() for processing the xml.
It is currently printing the whole xml . Is there is any way i can use etree.iterparse() from s3

```
txtFile = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=process)
data = txtFile['Body'].read()
context = etree.iterparse(data,events=("end",), tag="data-Id")
for event, elem in context:
    elem.attrib.get("data-id")
```

Comment: Try using `BytesIO`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63982552/407651

Comment: @mzjn its working thank you

Comment: That's great. Feel free to upvote the linked answer. I will vote to close this one as a duplicate.